# Regex to match comma separated values

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to Regex in Java and I wanted to know how can I build one that only takes a string that consists of one or two comma-separated lists of uppercase letters, separated by a single whitespace.

I would need to filter out strings that start with a comma, that end with a comma or strings that have multiple consecutive commas.

All these would be invalid:

- `"D,, D"`
- `"D D,,"`
- `"D, ,D"`
- `"D, ,,D"`
- `"D,, ,D"`
- `"D,,"`
- `",,A"`
- `",A"`
- `"A,"`

All these would be valid:

- `"D,D T,F"`
- `"D,D T"`
- `"A,A"`
- `"A"`

I used `(\s?("[\w\s]*"|\d*)\s?(,,|$))` for consecutive commas but it doesn't do the trick when the comma is at the end or beggining of one of the whitespace separated substring like `"D, ,D"`

Should I aim to split by whitespace and look for a simpler regex for each of the substrings?

Comment: reject if this `^\s*,|,\s*,|,\s*$` is **found**  Press [Java](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydqa2var) to test // or `split(",", -1)` and check if any entry is empty (only spaces)

Comment: Yes, it is valid. That would qualify as a single comma separated list, which is totally fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be something like this:

```
^[A-Z](,[A-Z])*( [A-Z](,[A-Z])*)*$
```

What happens here, is the following:

- We expect a letter, optionally followed by one or more times a comma-immediately-followed-by-another-letter.
- Then we optionally accept a space, and then the abovementioned pattern. And this is repeated.

Test: https://regex101.com/r/kzLhtw/1

You could, of course, slightly optimize the regex by making all capturing groups non-capturing: just put `?:` immediately behind the `(`, that is, `(?:`.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks, but I think that the entry `D T` actually matches. I updated the link to regex101 to include the testcase.

Comment: Right, my bad. I was too quick there =). Mind you though, you allow for multiple spaces! I noticed that with the other answer too. Maybe my mind is not there today but it seems OP is looking for one or two comma seperated lists. In the case of two lists the two lists are seperated by a space. Either way, you had my vote allready.

Answer (score 2):

You might use

```
^[A-Z](?: [A-Z])*(?:,[A-Z](?: [A-Z])*){0,2}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]` Match a single char A-Z
- `(?: [A-Z])*` Optionally repeat a space and and a single char A-Z
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,[A-Z](?: [A-Z])*` Match a comma, char A-Z followed by optionally repeat matching a space and a char A-Z
- `){0,2}` Close the group and repeat 0-2 times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aMEGe6/1)

Comment: Headsup @TheFourthBird. This would also match strings with multiple spaces. Note, there can be one **or** two comma seperated lists. These lists are seperated by a space. =). Thought it would be good to let you know. +

Comment: @JvdV I was reading this as one or two comma's where the uppercase characters are separated by a space.

Answer (score 1):

> *"a string that consists of one or two comma-separated lists of uppercase letters, separated by a single whitespace"*

Not sure how to *exactly* interpretate the above, but my reading is: One or two comma-seperated lists where each list may only consist of uppercase characters. In the case of two lists, the two lists are seperated by a single space.

You could try:

```
^(?!.* .* )[A-Z](?:[ ,][A-Z])*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Q1B0u/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?!.* .* )` - Negative lookahead to prevent two spaces present.
- `[A-Z]` - A single uppercase alpha-char.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `[ ,]` - A comma or space.
  - `[A-Z]` - A single uppercase alpha-char.
  - `)*` - Close non-capture group and match 0+ times upt to;
- `$` - End string anchor.

Comment: (I already upvoted, I think this would have less backtracking :-)) `^(?!\S+ \S+ )[A-Z](?:[ ,][A-Z])*$` https://regex101.com/r/9EXiga/1